# How can I use C++ enum types like C#?

Tags: c#, c++, enums

How can I use C++ enum types like C#?

consider following definition in c++ :

```
enum myEnum { A, B, C};
myEnum en = A;
```

Now I want to write line #2 as following line like C# :

```
myEnum en = myEnum.A;
```

??

Comment: FYI, I see that you recently edited the tags on this question to add C.  Bear in mind that C and C++ are very different languages, and both are very different from C#.  (Some might say that C is as different from modern C++ as C++ is from C#.)  As such, it's hard to answer both at the same time.  Perhaps you could clarify what it is that you're trying to do?

Comment: @Daniel : you are right, But in this scope ( Enums ) they have some common issues ! such as Enums use int data type ! and define like other. I have a lot of Enum Types, Then I want to separate them to best reading code. Thanks for all good answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++0x introduces `enum class` that does exactly what you want:

```
enum class myEnum { A, B, C };
myEnum en = myEnum::A;
```

In C, I would probably use good old prefixing:

```
enum myEnum { myEnum_A, myEnum_B, myEnum_C };
myEnum en = myEnum_A;
```

Comment: Now, Please tell me how can I do this in C ?

Comment: Your question has C++ tagged and you said C++, but now you say C?

Comment: @Behrouz: C doesn't have namespaces or scoping like this. You can't.

Answer (score 8):

Well, different rules in C++.  Closest you could get is this slight abomination:

```
namespace myEnum {
    enum myEnum { A, B, C};
}

myEnum::myEnum en = myEnum::A;
```

Comment: It is a very nice solution. But is there any other solution without using namespace ?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the question here? Your C# example will work as you have written it (although it doesn't match the .NET naming conventions...)

Comment: I think he wants to use the C# syntax in C++.