# Can't understand enums in C++, what are they actually ?

Tags: c++, enums

The last few years I programmed in C#, and I came back to C++ now. In C# enums act something like this:

```
enum myenum { a,b,c} 
myenum myinstance = myenum.a;
```

So I can do something like this:

```
enum myenum { a,b,c}     
enum myenum2 { a,b,c} 

myenum myinstance = myenum.a;
```

and everything will be fine.

In C++ it doesn't compile, moreover I can't now use `a` (or `b` or `c`) as class name or anything else, it seems like writing :

```
enum myenum { a, b };
```

Is the same as declaring global int variables :

```
int a =0, b=1;
```

I don't understand why the developers of C++ choose this type of behavior for enums, and what enums are? is it a type? or just something that the compiler replaces with some int declarations?

Comment: C++ developers chose this type of behaviours of enums because that's how enums behave in C (which is the language from the beginning of the  seventies).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use C++ enum types like C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730635/how-can-i-use-c-enum-types-like-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `enum class`s instead if you have access to a C++11 compiler. These are also known as strongly-typed enums.

```
enum class myenum { a,b,c};     
enum class myenum2 { a,b,c}; 

myenum myinstance = myenum::a;
```

This has the behavior you are expecting.

Note, however, that they are not implicitly convertible to `int` like classic C++ `enum`s are.

***To your question at the end***:
C++ enums **are** distinct types, but unfortunately they are implicitly convertible to `int`, and as you have noticed already, they don't have their own namespace. This is a historical artifact of the language and its C heritage. The strongly-typed enums I have described here have neither of these problems.

For some more information about them and some background, take a look at [this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html)

Answer (score 3):

C++ enum values are defined globaly, so as you noticed, if you write an enum like this:

```
enum my_enum { a , b , c };
```

`a` , `c` ,  and `d` are global names.

The classic solution to this is to prefix the values with an identifier, the name of the enum for example:

```
enum my_enum
{
    MY_ENUM_A , 
    MY_ENUM_B , 
    MY_ENUM_C
};
```

However C++11 added strongly typed enums, which defines its values in a scoped form:

```
enum class my_enum { a , b , c };

my_enum one = my_enum::a; //ok
my_enum two = a;          //This not compiles, because a is not defined in this scope.
```

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to encase your enum in namespace so you can do that

```
namespace myenum2
{
enum myenum2_enum
{ a,b,c };
}

namespace myenum
{
enum myenum_enum
{ a,b,c };
}
```

then you can use myenum::a or myenum2::b, etc etc... comming from C# i know how you feel that was the closest thing that 'felt' like the same thing since enums themselves are a collection of globals